# DateTime or Integer for Model Run Date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

I have some fact tables in my data model with millions of rows.
Each table has its own refresh cycle.
Now I have added the system date into every table within Power Query as a new column to show the last refresh.
I am using this function:

```
DateTime.LocalNow() as datetime
```

Since the tables contain millions of rows I am asking which data type is here the best?
I could transform the DateTime to a decimal number and then changing with FORMAT in Power BI and a measure the decimal number back to DateTime, if necessary.
How would you do that?
Model Run Date as a decimal number or as DateTime?
Is there any difference from a memory point of view?

Comment: Different datatype can have different compression in memory. 
You can check which column in your model need at most space. Beside, o you really need add this column to main dataset? Maybe you can create new table, contain only 1 row with  info.

https://www.sqlbi.com/tv/checking-model-size-using-vertipaq-analyzer-in-dax-studio/

Comment: @msta42a: Thank you so much for your support! How would you build a new table, that contains for each table the information of the last refresh time? The refresh times are different between each table.

Comment: I haven't tested it for your scenario, but you can reference one "query"/"Table" in another as a source. example. I have dataset name "Salary" and some column Date, Spend, Name.
I can create a new blank Query where in advanced editor i can put:

let
    Source = Salary[Date]
    #"Removed Duplicates" = List.Distinct(Source)
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"

That gives me a list of unique Dates from my Salary Table. In the next step you can add column with source table name. Repeat for all table, then append queries

Comment: @msta42a: Awesome! Thanks for that. And how can I add the Model Run data for each table into this new table? I mean, I still need this information in the original table, right? The new table is just the extract with the model run dates. How will this new table help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power BI uses columnar compression such that the memory size of a column is mostly dependent on the number of distinct values in that column. Because of that, any column with just a single value is going to be negligible in terms of memory and the data type isn't going to make any material difference.